# How to separate page vertically with drawing a vertical line in html

Tags: html, css

I'm a newbie in html and try to find separate a webpage vertically with drawing vertical line but can't find
Most of them that I found is initializing width with 50% and 50% or something. like below.

```
<div id="left" style="float:left; width:15%;" > This is left panel </div>
<div id="right" style="float:left; width:85%;"> This is right panel </div>
```

However, I want to make a vertical line between two panels.

How can I do that?
Thanks

**EDIT:**

```css
.head {
  background-image: url(../img/internet-of-things-ionicframework.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  ##background: #000;
  padding: 50px 0;
  min-height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.head-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.head-content h2 {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.head-content p {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.head-content .btn {
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}

main {
  min-height: 500px;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

footer {
  padding: 30px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #888;
  background: #222;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Welcome</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#" id="deploy">Deploy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div id="container" style="width:100%;">
    <div id="left" style="float:left; width:15%;"> This is left panel </div>
    <div id="right" style="float:left; width:85%;"> This is right panel </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use `border` and 100% height for divs

Comment: Can you explain in more details...? :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `calc()` and following css

```
div#container {
  height: calc(100vh - 70px);
  float: left;
}
#left,
#right {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}
#right{
  border-left:1px solid;
}
```

```css
.head {
  background-image: url(../img/internet-of-things-ionicframework.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background: #000;
  padding: 50px 0;
  min-height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.head-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.head-content h2 {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.head-content p {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.head-content .btn {
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}

main {
  min-height: 500px;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

footer {
  padding: 30px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #888;
  background: #222;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
div#container {
    height: calc(100vh - 70px);
    float: left;
}
#left,
#right {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}
#right{
  border-left:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#" id="deploy">Deploy</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<div id="container" style="width:100%;">
  <div id="left" style="float:left; width:15%;"> This is left panel </div>
  <div id="right" style="float:left; width:85%;"> This is right panel </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hm.. Doesn't work... let me edit my question and gives you whole code of my html and css

Comment: Thanks How can I make the line be thicker?

Comment: Also may I know what was the problem?

Comment: For thicker line, increase `border-width`, and for problem, if you want to set `height:100%` of any element, it's parent height must be fixed.

Comment: Ah ha Thanks for the answer and comments! :) I really appreciated! hope you have a great one! :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
#left{
  height:100vh;
  border-right:1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

#right{
  height:100vh;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="left" style="float:left; width:15%;" > This is left panel </div>
<div id="right" style="float:left; width:85%;"> This is right panel </div>
```

Comment: Hm.. Doesn't work... let me edit my question and gives you whole code of my html and css

Answer (score 0):

You want to divide a page in two sections with a line in the middle? Try this code:

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  border:none;
  padding:0;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

html {
  height:100%;
}

body {
  min-height:100%;
}

.content {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  display:table;
}

.sided-section {
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  display:table-cell;
}

.section-line {
  position:absolute;
  width:4px;
  height:100%;
  background:black;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -2px; /*Half size of width*/
  z-index:999;
}

.section-content {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   padding:4px; /*Recomended to the section-line don't overlay the content*/
}

.right-section {
  background:lightcoral;
}

.left-section {
  background:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  
  <div class="section-line"></div>
  
  <section class="sided-section right-section">
    <div class="section-content">
      <p>
        At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat
      </p><br>
      
      <p>
        At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat
      </p><br>

      <p>
        At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat
      </p><br>

      <p>
        At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat
      </p> 
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random" alt="Image Right"/>     
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="sided-section left-section">
    <div class="section-content">
      <p>
        At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat
      </p>
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random" alt="Image Right"/>
    </div>      
  </section>

</div>
```

You can also check out the code on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L7rxasbh/3/). You can create a solution with less components but will give less control.